# Am I in danger of being banned?

Tags: support, asking-questions, specific-user, post-ban

I wanted to post a new question, but when I try to do so I got a warning:

> Wait! Some of your past questions have not been well-received, and
>   you're in danger of being blocked from asking any more.

I am a bit confused about this. Would someone help me understand which questions haven't been well received?

Also, if possible, would I be able to get feedback on the question that I currently have with suggestions on how to make them follow the standard of the site?

Comment: I guess it was [this self-deleted duplicate](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1353912/finding-sin1-circ) together with the fact that your only later question also is marked as a duplicate that triggered the warning. The algorithm for the warning pop-up isn't very sophisticated. You're not actually being in danger of being question-banned. Even rate-limiting seems _very_ unlikely.

Comment: @DanielFischer: Ok, thanks. If I have a question that is marked as a duplicate, is it appropriate to delete?

Comment: That depends. As long as it has no answers, it is your call whether to delete or not. Deleting it might trigger the warning to pop up when not having deleted the question wouldn't. But with an overall question record like yours, you need not worry about that.

Comment: Not sure whether I should close as a duplicate of [this question](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/20693/warning-appeared-when-i-ask-a-question-but-i-have-a-good-history).

Comment: @DanielFischer: Ok, feel free to delete/close this question.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You're not; your account triggered a warning for a ban that is no longer in effect (it has been superseded by [rolling rate limits](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/asking-rate-limited)) - the ban itself was turned off but not the warning.

There's *another* ban and another warning to go with it that are still in play, but you're *far* from qualifying for either.

We're discussing how to best disable the obsolete warning internally right now; sorry for the confusion!

This is now disabled for users who've earned even a modicum of reputation. There are other warnings that will kick in at various (considerably more nuanced) thresholds, all of which should do a better job of explaining the problem.